# Set up a computer connecting through my laptop to be on the same network as the laptop

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a desktop PC which currently has no wireless. My home network is a wireless network. I have it successfully connected to my network through my laptop (with built in wireless) using Ubuntu's Shared network option. However, this leaves it with an IP address 10.42.x.x . I would like to get it onto the main 10.0.0.x network so computers on that network other than my laptop can access. It would preferably have a static IP address as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be easier to purchase a [wireless network card](http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&source=hp&q=wireless+network+card&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=Uj0yS6KXOYT-NdaTmY4J&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CFQQrQQwAg) than trying to make the desktop work with a laptop shared network connection? The time you spend trying to get the machine setup that way could well be spent on other things.

Good luck on your project.

Comment: This is a temporary solution. I'm buying the wireless adapter at the same time as other parts. However there is no delivery from that store until after new years. I'm not paying shipping for a week and a halfs use.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to get the shared network option to use the router's DHCP server, or vice versa i think